# What are the file formats that Android VideoPlayer support?

Tags: android, android-video-player

What are the file formats that Android VideoPlayer support?

And the differences between the VideoView and VideoPlayer in Android.

I am looking for on tutorials, videos, forums answers, etc.

Anything related to this...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> what are file formats android video
>   player can support in android?

They are listed in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

> and differentiate the video view and
>   video player in android..

There is a widget named `VideoView`. There is nothing in the Android SDK named "video player". There is a class named `MediaPlayer`, which can be used with a `SurfaceView` to play back videos. In fact, all VideoView does is wrap up a `MediaPlayer` and a `SurfaceView`.

> i am looking on the tutorils, videos,
>   forums answer, etc.

[Here are](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Video/) [two projects](http://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry) from one of my books demonstrating video playback.